# How To Fix memory leak in in Reaact Native?

Tags: android, performance, react-native, memory-leaks

I have a problem with my application that is a memory leak, where when the application that I developed during the debugger hangs.

I have unmounted state and event

Following a warning in debugger mode:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in PTRViewAndroid (at Home.js:187)
```

Comment: Hmm, if by "I have unmounted state and event" you mean you have already added code that cancels the events you know about into `componentWillUnmount` I would try commenting out everything inside the component's methods and see if the error is still there. If that makes it go away, then uncomment half of the things in the methods, and narrow it down that way. If that doesn't make it go away I'm not sure, maybe check if you are using some Higher-Order Component or something?

Comment: What you mean with Higher-Order Component ?.

Comment: Things like `withRouter`. You would use them like this `const MyComponentWithRouter = withRouter(MyComponent)` They used to be more popular in React then they are now. I'm not sure if they ever got popular in React Native or not though. I have had issues with them before, doing things I didn't expect.